# Jquery animation "Open" and "Closes" instantly after second press

Tags: jquery

When I click the `a_demo_threee` div it opens and when I click in the `Document`
it closes; so far so good, but when I try to open it the second time it opens and closes instantly. And now I want to know what the problem is and how to fix it.

Here is the Jquery code for a closer look visit this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/93/)

```
$(".a_demo_threee").click(function () { //opens the login

$(".a_demo_threee").animate({
    "width": "300px",
    "height": "200px",
}, 1000);

$("#contentlogin").show();
timer = setTimeout(closelogin, 1);
});

function closelogin() {
clearTimeout(timer);
$(document).click(function () {
    $(".a_demo_threee").animate({
        "width": "42px",
        "height": "39px",
    }, 1000);

    $("#contentlogin").hide();
});}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you complicating(setting a time out and clearing it.) the simple things. Actually `event bubbling` is the problem that your code is currently facing. You can use `event.stopPropagation` to block the event bubbling up from that `anchor` element to the `document`.

Please read this : [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(".a_demo_threee").click(function (e) { //opens the login

    e.stopPropagation();

    $(".a_demo_threee").animate({
        "width": "300px",
        "height": "200px",
    }, 1000);

    $("#contentlogin").show();
});

    $(document).click(function () {
        $(".a_demo_threee").animate({
            "width": "42px",
            "height": "39px",
        }, 1000);

        $("#contentlogin").hide();
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/95/)

---

You can clear up the animation queue by using the [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function.

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/99/)

Comment: This seems working fine but When you click on the opend thing like 15 time or more it seems that when i click the Document it waits some seconds before it closes.

and the same counts when its closed and you click the document Several times it waits some seconds to open it

Comment: @JanAckermann See my updated answer, It will solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are adding two click handlers: One to expand/show and one to minimize/hide. I would refactor the code so there is one click handler that expands the div if it's hidden and minimizes it if it's shown. See below and working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQS8s/97/

```
$("#contentlogin").hide(); //hides the content so its invisibil on the refresh/load of the website

$(".a_demo_threee").click(function () {
    if ($("#contentlogin:hidden").length > 0) {
        openLogin();
    } else {
        closeLogin();
    }
});

function openLogin() {
    $(".a_demo_threee").animate({
        "width": "300px",
        "height": "200px",
    }, 1000);
    $("#contentlogin").show();
}

function closeLogin() {
    $(".a_demo_threee").animate({
        "width": "42px",
        "height": "39px",
    }, 1000);
    $("#contentlogin").hide();
}
```

Comment: But OP wants to revert the element back while clicking on the document.

Comment: But there is a thing when it closes when i click .a_demo_threee.
later there will be inputs and when i click the input it also clicks 
the close function. So that dose not work for me.